# Multiple paths for subrepositories

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I have main repository and 12 subrepositories in it. `.hgsub` contains mappings of local paths and repository hosting URLs. Besides default pull/push URLs for subrepositories, I need to be able to push each subrepository to another server as a standalone repository. So, I add new path alias in `.hg/hgrc` of each subrepository.

The problem is that aliases are not save anywhere except my local machine, so when I do clean clone of main repository, this aliases are gone and I need to setup them again.

Can I permanently save this path aliases in repository configuration file or maybe there's some workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option available to you is to keep a .hgrc snippet in place in the parent repository filled with `[subpaths]` entries.  For example create `subpaths.hgrc` as a tracked file in your repository:

```
[subpaths]
repoa = http://remote/path/to/repo/a
repob = http://remote/path/to/repo/b
```

Then when you want to initialize those repositories you add this line to your clone's `.hg/hgrc`:

```
%include ../subpaths.hgrc
```

and then comment it out when you want the repoa and repob paths being their usual, local selves.